# Multiple components including Loading Spinner, sometimes simultaneously

Tags: reactjs

In my app there are multiple components calling the Loading spinner (including the top-level `App`), sometimes simultaneously, as they're doing their async fetches. I need to restrict the Loading spinner to be just 1 element on the page at any time. Other than the JS `document.getElementById()` is there a better way to do this? I don't want to bring the Loader into the top-level `App` and have Child->Parent callbacks on every start/stop: that will cause redraws of the entire app from top to bottom again.

```
function App() {

const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
useEffect(() => {    
    //...
    finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
    }        
}, []); 

// JSX includes sub-components with their own Loading integration
return (
    {/* ... */}
    {isLoading && <Loading/> }
    {/* ... */}
);
```

Sub-Component

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

return (
    {/* ... */}
    {isLoading && <Loading/> }
    {/* ... */}
);
```

Loading Component

```
export default function Loading() {
    return (
        <div class="spinner">
            <div class="fa-3x spinner-front">
                <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="spinner-back"></div>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: Try and check out react-query, which should eleviate all those problems.

Comment: I already use Axios. The problem isn't data fetching, it's how to detect MinStart/MaxStop for Loading overlays. But I think I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191525/react-how-to-detect-when-all-sub-components-of-a-parent-component-are-visible We have to track all of our operations and show/hide the Loader in one place.

Comment: React query and axios operate on different levels. Adios is how to get the data while react is how to access and cache the data from axios. It also allows you to access all loading states etc.